# Execute and delete command from a file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have multiple files with an insanely long list of commands. I can't run them all in one go, so I need a smart way to read and execute from file as well as delete the command after completion.

So far I have tried

```
for i in filename.txt ; do ; execute $i ; sed -s 's/$i//' ; done ;
```

but it doesn't work. Before I introduced `sed`, `$i` was executing. Now even that is not working.

I thought of a workaround where I will read first line and delete first line till file is empty.

Any better ideas or commands?

Comment: You might want to clarify what you are asking for by providing an example.

Comment: Why can't you run it all in one go?  The commands in a file will be executed sequentially.  Are you worried about crashes while the script is running? How complex are the commands that you're running?  Are they all single line commands?  Do they involve I/O redirection?

Comment: Also, what is the significance of `excecute`? Presumably that's a typo for `execute`, but is it a special command on your system?  It isn't a standard Unix command.  There is an `exec` in shells, but you probably don't want to be using it.

Comment: Note that `for i in filename.txt` executes the loop with precisely one value for `$i`, namely `filename.txt`.  It seems likely you were trying something like `for i in $(<filename.txt);` if all the commands are single words, or `while read i; do … done < filename.txt` if you need to read lines rather than words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, list.txt is your file containing commands.

**Make sure you backup the command file before running**.

```
while read line; do $line;sed -i '1d' list.txt;done < "list.txt"
```

sed -i edits in-place so list.txt will be changed along the loop and you will end up with a empty file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
while read -r -- i; do $i; sed -i "0,/$i/s/$i//;/^$/d" filename.txt; done < filename.txt
```

The file is read into the loop. Each line is executed, and the sed command will delete only the first entry it finds, then delete the empty line.

Comment: What happens as the file is rewritten while it is also being read?  It isn't clear that the behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: The file gets changed, but the sed command ensures only the command that was executed is removed. You can test it out on some code.

Comment: I'm having problems getting anything deleted from the command file.  Even after several hundred lines have been executed, the source file is still the original size — all the lines are still there.  I had to use `-i.bak` on Mac OS X; the backup suffix is mandatory.  So, I remain to be convinced.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one way to do it is to have the source file of all the commands to be executed, and the script that executes the commands also writes a second log file that lists the files as they are executed.
If you need to resume the process, you work on the lines in the source file that are not present in the log file.

```
logfile=commands.log
srcfile=commands.src
oldfile=commands.old

trap "mv $oldfile $logfile; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

[ -f $logfile ] || cp /dev/null $logfile
cp $logfile $oldfile

comm -23 $srcfile $logfile |
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" >> $oldfile
    ($line) < /dev/null
done

mv $oldfile $logfile
trap 0
```